# Android - Problem in using the Google pdf viewer in webview

Tags: android, pdf, viewer

I have seen lot of threads about loading a PDF in Android Webview. But I didn't see the issue what I am getting.

I am using Google PDF viewer to load the URL in the Webview which will give a PDF as response.

I am setting the following properties to my webview

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
Webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);


String url = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + "my url";
mWebview.loadUrl(url);
```

I am able load the PDF with the above given code. The issue I have is,

Once after loading the full page, a empty line is keep on getting inserted in top and bottom of page. So my page is looking like the one given below.

```
empty line
empty line
empty line
....
pdf content
empty line
empty line
empty line
....
```

The page is keep on increasing with empty lines.

Comment: Can be closed under: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong with Google only, now I am not getting this issue, it works fine.